# How can I generate deb installable file from the python files in my ROS package (script folder)?

Tags: ros, python, script, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

How can I generate deb installable file from the python files in my package(in the script folder), so I can deliver the deb file to the client who can run the python executables in the package?

For example, I just completed the ROS tutorial and created the beginner_tutorials package in my catkin workspace. I also completed the Simple Publisher and Subscriber tutorials which mean the python talker.py and listener.py in the script folder in the beginner_tutorials package.Then I run the following command in the package folder,~/ROS/catkin_workspace/src/beginner_tutorials:

$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

$ fakeroot debian/rules binary

So it generated the deb file. After I installed the deb to a new machine and I try to run the command:

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py

After the installation on the new machine. I can't run the talker and listener. There is no python file in the /opt/ros/kinetic/lib. but look inside of the deb file, there are python files in the /opt/ros/kinetic/lib folder. I don't know where the python file went after install the deb file. I was wondering how can I export the package with python script to a installable deb file and after I install the deb file on a new machine, I can run the python executable file on the new machine?

If someone can give me some hints or guidance, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267978/how-can-i-generate-deb-installable-file-from-the-python-files-in-my-ros-package(script-folder),-so-i-can-deliver-the-deb-file-to-the-client-who-can-install-deb-file-and-run-the-python-executables-on-their-machine?/) by [freeleons](https://answers.ros.org/users/31430/freeleons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote this document in word format and copy pasted here. If you want to see the prettier formated document or discuss about the topic shoot me an email at: freeleons at qq.com

Section 1, Package beginner_tutorial into Debian File
This tutorial assumes you have already created the ros beginner_tutorial package by following the ROS beginner tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). You can also refer to the zipped package files which is beginner_tutorials.tar.gz and beginner_tutorials_cpp.tar.gz, and experiment with it.
Install Python files using deb
In the beginner_tutorials ROS package folder, the tree structure of the folder is as following:

To add the python source code files to the deb, you need to add following lines to the CMakeLists.txt:
FILE(GLOB openag_script_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script/*.*")
FILE(GLOB openag_subdirectory_script_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script/srv/*.*")

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
${openag_script_files}
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
${openag_subdirectory_script_files}
  DESTINATION "${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}/srv")

If you don’t add the code above to the CMakeLists.txt file, your deb file do not contain the python executable files. After install the deb, the python executable files will NOT be installed on your machine.
Another alternative way of install python script files in the deb file, it is writing following macros. It has the same effect as catkin_install_python:
install(PROGRAMS
script/listener.py
script/talker.py
script/add_two_ints_client.py
script/add_two_ints_server.py
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(PROGRAMS
script/srv/_AddTwoInts.py
script/srv/**init**.py
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}/srv
)

The following code block which should be placed in the CMakeLists.txt will add launch folder and launch file in the deb installable file:
install(DIRECTORY launch/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)

Then run the following command in the package folder to generate Debian source folder, my case is ~/ROS/catkin_workspace/src/beginner_tutorials:
$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

It creates Debian folder in the package folder. Then run the following command in the package folder to generate deb file:
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary

It generates the deb file, ros-kinetic-beginner-tutorials_0.1.0-0xenial_amd64.deb, in the src folder. Then you can give deb to someone to install it.
Install C++ files using deb
In the beginner_tutorials_cpp ROS package folder, the tree structure of the folder is as following:

To add build target/executable files using catkin_make, you need to add the following line to the CMakeLists.txt:
add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

To add executables to the deb file, you need add following lines to the CMakeLists.txt:
install(TARGETS talker listener add_two_ints_server add_two_ints_client
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

If you don’t add the code above to the CMakeLists.txt file, your deb file do not contain the C++ executable files. After install the deb, the C++ executable files will NOT be installed on your machine.
Then run the following command in the package folder to generate Debian source folder, my case is ~/ROS/catkin_workspace/src/beginner_tutorials:
$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

It creates Debian folder in the package folder. Then run the following command in the package folder to generate deb file:
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary

It generates the deb file, ros-kinetic-beginner-tutorials-cpp_0.1.0-0xenial_amd64.deb, in the src folder. Then you can give deb to someone to install the deb file.
Install the deb file on Ubuntu
You can install it using sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file followed by sudo apt-get install -f or you can install it by double click it and choose install.
After installation, you can find the python or C++ executable in the folder, /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/beginner_tutorials and in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/beginner_tutorials_cpp, you can use rosrun to run the executables.
Section 2, Package RoboteQ ROS Package Into Debian File
This section introduces how to package the RoboteQ ROS into deb file. This tutorial assumes you have followed the document, “Modify RoboteQ Driver ROS Driver Source Code and so We Can Sending Commands to RoboteQ FBL2360 Brushless DC Motor Controller.docx”, and have got all the package source code prepared.
Before use the command, bloom-generate, you need to add the dependency to the rosdep lists. rosdep does not like to check out private repositories, the best solution is to manually check it out on your system and point your rosdep lists at it, by adding a line to /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d like:
yaml file:///home/myuser/myrosdistro/rosdep/private.yaml /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
The private.yaml will look something like:
my_private_package1:
ubuntu: ros-hydro-my-private-package1
In our case we add the follow line to the 20-default.list:
yaml file:///home/freeleons/ws/src/roboteq/roboteq_msgs/roboteq_msgs.yaml
We add the following lines to the roboteq_msgs.yaml:
roboteq_msgs:
ubuntu: ros-kinetic-roboteq-msgs
Now run bloom-generate:
bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

If it still want to use rosdep to find the key, you need to run rosdep update. Then try to run rosdep resolve roboteq-msgs, if it successfully resolve the key. Next run the fakeroot command:
fakeroot debian/rules binary

it gives following error:

dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver.substvars -l/home/freeleons/ws_copy/src/roboteq_driver/debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver//opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/roboteq_driver/driver_node
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't parse dependency ros-kinetic-roboteq_msgs
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: error occurred while parsing Build-Depends/Build-Depends-Arch
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver.substvars -l/home/freeleons/ws_copy/src/roboteq_driver/debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver//opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/roboteq_driver/driver_node returned exit code 255
debian/rules:51: recipe for target 'override_dh_shlibdeps' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_shlibdeps] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/freeleons/ws_copy/src/roboteq_driver'
debian/rules:23: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2

Now open the Debian control file in the ~/ws/src/roboteq_driver/Debian folder, change ros-kinetic-roboteq_msgs which appeared twice in the file to ros-kinetic-roboteq-msgs:
dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver.substvars -l/home/freeleons/ws_copy/src/roboteq_driver/debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver//opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/roboteq_driver/driver_node
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't parse dependency ros-kinetic-roboteq_msgs
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: error occurred while parsing Build-Depends/Build-Depends-Arch
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver.substvars -l/home/freeleons/ws_copy/src/roboteq_driver/debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver//opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ debian/ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/roboteq_driver/driver_node returned exit code 255

if you run into this problem and the error message as below:

```
cd /home/patrik/roboteq_ws/src/roboteq/roboteq_driver
```

dh_auto_configure: cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var -DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic returned exit code 1
debian/rules:26: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_configure' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_configure] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/patrik/roboteq_ws/src/roboteq/roboteq_driver'
debian/rules:23: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2

Use following command to save the error to the error log:
fakeroot debian/rules binary > error.log
Show the result as below:
patrik@patrik-T58-D:~/roboteq_ws/src/roboteq/roboteq_driver$ fakeroot debian/rules binary > error.log
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "serial" with any
  of the following names:

serialConfig.cmake
    serial-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "serial" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "serial_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "serial"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "serial" with any
  of the following names:

serialConfig.cmake
    serial-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "serial" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "serial_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "serial"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

dh_auto_configure: cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var -DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_configure] Error 255
make: *** [binary] Error 2

You can run the following command to solve the problem:
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-serial
Now it should be able to generalize the following fiile:
ros-kinetic-roboteq-driver_0.2.0-0xenial_amd64.deb
To generate the ros-kinetic-roboteq-msgs_0.2.0-0xenial_amd64.deb
file: run the bloom-generate and debian/rules binary command in the source folder

Reference:
[1] https://github.com/mikeferguson/buildbot-ros/blob/master/documentation/private_repositories.md   as below:

---

Originally posted by [freeleons](https://answers.ros.org/users/31430/freeleons/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-08**:
Please use the `101010` button to format your code.